# How to check the application path installed with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

Install three applications, A, B, and C, on one PC as ClickOnce.

And is there a way to know the installation path for B and C when you run application A?

My final goal is to get the installation paths of B and C from A and run these two programs from A.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your ClickOnce application from windows start menu path, for that you need application's publisher name, suite name and product name. You can set those information from project property page -> publish section -> click on options button and set publisher name, suite name and product name.

Now you can use below code to start any ClickOnce application.

```
string StartMenuProgramDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs);
string Publisher = "<<Publisher Name>>";
string SuiteName = "<<Suite Name>>";
string ProductName = "<<Product Name>>.appref-ms";

Process.Start(Path.Combine(StartMenuProgramDirectory, Publisher, SuiteName, ProductName));
```

If you still want to know installation location of ClickOnce application, I am using below way (not sure this is ideal way or not)

You need to set your application display icon with below Code. (This will used to display icon in Control Panel -> Programs and Features)

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed && ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun)
    {
        string IconPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Resources", "MyIcon.ico");

        if (File.Exists(IconPath))
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
            string[] subKeys = registryKey.GetSubKeyNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < subKeys.Length; i++)
            {
                RegistryKey subRegistryKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(subKeys[i], true);
                object DisplayName = subRegistryKey.GetValue("DisplayName");
                if (DisplayName != null && (DisplayName + "").ToUpper() == ("<<Product Name>>").ToUpper())
                {
                    subRegistryKey.SetValue("DisplayIcon", IconPath);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, Application's ClickOnce registry file is set with icon's path and your icon is available in installation directory, later you can fetch display icon's path with below code and based on that you can also able to find installation location.

```
string DisplayIconPath;
RegistryKey InstalledClickOncesRegistryKey = null;
RegistryKey InstalledProgramRegistryKey = null;

InstalledClickOncesRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall");
if (InstalledClickOncesRegistryKey != null && InstalledClickOncesRegistryKey.SubKeyCount > 0)
{
    string[] InstalledClickOncesList = InstalledClickOncesRegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames();
    if (InstalledClickOncesList != null && InstalledClickOncesList.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var InstalledClickOnces in InstalledClickOncesList)
        {
            InstalledProgramRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\" + InstalledClickOnces);

            if (InstalledProgramRegistryKey != null && InstalledProgramRegistryKey.ValueCount > 0)
            {
                string RegistryApplicationName = Convert.ToString(InstalledProgramRegistryKey.GetValue("DisplayName"));

                if (string.Equals(RegistryApplicationName, "<<Product Name>>"))
                    DisplayIconPath = Convert.ToString(InstalledProgramRegistryKey.GetValue("DisplayIcon"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to know where the applications were installed?

Comment: I have updated my answer.